# Are there any cloud-based file sharing and storage services that allow upload from a URL via API?

Tags: webapp-rec

I've been looking for a service like this, but have had no luck, so far. Perhaps I overlooked something during my search.

I need to find a cloud-based file-storage and sharing service that will let me upload a file via API by providing a URL to the file (rather than posting the file).

Use-case #1: Let's say I'm using Drawloop's cloud-based mail-merge solution to create mail-merged PDFs via API. Each time I create a PDF, I get a URL to the created file. I'd like to be able to upload this file to a file-storage service without having to download it first - so pass in the URL to the file and have the file-storage system retrieve it from the URL. I'm creating the file in the cloud - why should I have to download it first, in order to get it into my cloud-based file-storage system?

Use-case #2: I'm using Formstack to collect form submissions along with uploaded files. Formstack stores the files on S3, but I'd also like to store them in my own cloud-based file-storage system. Formstack gives me the URL for each uploaded file, and I'd like to be able to pass that URL to my file-storage system and have the system retrieve the file directly from the URL.

Surely somebody's doing this already, right?

Answer (score -1):

You can also try the AWS S3 service also.

Comment: How? Why? Provide some more information.

Answer (score -1):

Formstack now integrates with both Box and DropBox.

Answer (score -2):

The article at the link below may be useful; however these are apps which allow uploading from a URL to your dropbox and similar.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-ways-send-files-dropbox-dropbox/

Answer (score -2):

Use [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com/) to upload any files directly from the web, Facebook, Instagram, Dropbox or Google Drive. The have iOS widget as well.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product? If so, you need to disclose it.